# Keras TypeError when loading a model with a custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have a custom Keras layer in a model that I am saving. I want to load back this model. This is the code I am using to do so:

```
self.model = load_model(path, custom_objects={'MyLayer': MyLayer, 'custom_loss_fn': custom_loss_fn})
```

This is the custom layer I am using in the model:

```
class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(units, **kwargs)
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, values):
        ...

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
          'w1': self.W1,
          'w2': self.W2,
          'v': self.V,
        })
        return config
```

When I try to load the model I get the below error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'
```

Why is that?

### Update

I am saving the model with kera's `ModelCheckpoint` callback. Could this be a compatibility issue?

Comment: what happens if you put units = self.units in the init func at the top?

Comment: you mean self.units = units?

Comment: yeah, does that resolve the problem?

Comment: and try putting the super() statement at the bottom in the init function

Comment: none of the above worked.

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the init function accordingly

```
def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):    
   self.units = units
   ...
   super(MyCustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```